# How to move a Window that is taller than the screen so that the lower hidden part is shown

Tags: windows-7, windows, remote-desktop

How to move an application Window that is taller than the screen so that the lower hidden part is shown? I tried using Alt-Del-M (or Alt-Space-M for direct display) to move the Window up but it doesn't work. I've also tried to increase RDP resolution to full screen and font DPI is at 100%.

Note: I'm connecting to the Windows 7 machine using RDP. The app doesn't have a maximum option and I'm not able to change the GUI.

[image: Screen]

Comment: Can you resize the application window from the very top (the edge above the minimize/maximize/exit buttons) and it creates scrollbars so that you can get to all the application parts you require? This YouTube explains the options potentially available: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e3XntupxxtA - the application developer, however, can prevent windows from being resized. if this is the case you'll have no other options.

Comment: You could try a tool like [AltDrag](https://stefansundin.github.io/altdrag/) which will allow you to grab the window anywhere and move it, as long as you keep the Alt key pressed.

Comment: Additionally, the key command sequence`Alt + Space M <arrow key>` will move the window whatever direction the arrow points. That said, your RDP client shoudl show scroll bars if the remote hosts resolution is greater than the clients. Perhaps the `RDCMan` remote desktop viewer application (in the windows server resource kit) is a better tool for this usecase.

Comment: Helpful maybe http://superuser.com/questions/162830/what-to-do-if-a-window-is-bigger-than-the-screen-resolution and http://superuser.com/questions/136994/win-7-how-can-i-resize-a-window-to-make-it-much-bigger-than-my-screen

Comment: You could try a differnet tool, like TeamViewer, LogMeIn or GoToMyPc or similar?

Comment: Thank you for asking this. I have the identical issue with windows since ever. I never found a way.

Answer (score 1):

Set your screen display mode to 90' rotation... okay, it's a buzz getting used to side-ways mouse movement coordination, but as your horizontal screen resolution is greater (than vertical) - hopefully your window will play nicely with "Windows" and show correctly on this longer vertical screen layout (eg. sideways).

Turning your monitor sideways is optional, depending on how much time you need to use this particular application.

*NOTE : Rethinking my above thoughts... on a remote connection, it should feed to you correctly (long vertical screen) and you should be able to scroll within your screen... I think... it does on my RealVNC connections to a vertical placed monitor?*

Comment: In Windows 7 you can press CTRL-ALT-[arrow key] to do this rotation - up for normal, down for 180°, right/left for 90°/270°. Not sure if the keyboard shortcut will translate through the RDP though.

Answer (score 0):

A multiple-monitor setup might also work, depending on whether the RDP will work with it. If you can extend your local machine's desktop with a one-over-the-other layout, you may then be able to further increase the RDP's vertical resolution, giving you more space to drag that window upward.