# How to partially move a window off-screen?

Tags: windows, window

I tried moving the window with alt+space+m but it always get pinned to the end of the screen. I want to move its head out of the screen so I can increase my visibility by removing the headers. Any setting that will help me?

I'm using windows server 2019 data center.

OK - I installed AltDrag as suggested by [this comment](https://superuser.com/questions/946829/how-to-move-a-window-that-is-taller-than-the-screen-so-that-the-lower-hidden-par#comment1290038_946829) and yes I can stick the top of the window above the screen resolution but now I can't resize its bottom to be larger then the screen height. Any ideas?

I tried killing windows explorer as well.

Answer (score 3):

Windows 10 does not let you move a window above the top of the screen
(I haven't tested for earlier Windows versions).

The old method of <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> does move the window
above the top, but it will snap back when going out of "move" mode.

You will need a program for overcoming this "helpful" feature of Windows,
for example using
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

The following AutoHotkey script will move the currently active window
to a position of 10 pixels above the top of the screen and set its height
to make it reach the bottom of the screen.
It uses the [WinMove](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinMove.htm)
command and is triggered by <kbd>F10</kbd>.

```
F10::WinMove , -10, , A_ScreenHeight+10, "A"
```

Or for the version 1 of AutoHotkey:

```
F10::WinMove A,,,-10,, A_ScreenHeight+10
```

Modify this one-liner according to your needs and put it into a text file with the
extension `.ahk`. Double-click to start. While the script is "running", the hotkey is usable. Right-click the script's tray icon to stop execution.
If useful, it can be copied to the
[Startup folder](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/startup-folder-in-windows-8).